# How to create a separate table for each user/store user specific data using sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, database-table

I am using sqlite3 for python to build a notes management application using tkinter. I wanted to know how can I create a separate table to handle each user's data (contains id, tags and memo for each note) separately. Is it possible to create separate table for each user in database?

Comment: Maintaining a separate _table_ for each user is a bad idea.  Instead, just use a single table with a column for the user ID.

Comment: each user can have multiple notes and hence can access them if he/she has seperate table

Comment: "each user can have multiple notes and hence can access them if he/she has seperate table" - what does having multiple notes have to do with having separate tables for each user? Just add a `UserId` column to your `Notes` table and make it a component column of the table's Composite Primary Key (for referentially-secure foreign keys).

Comment: ok will try thanks @Dai